# Custom iPhone SDK location

Tags: iphone, macos, sdk, static-libraries

I've been developing a collection of static libraries for use with iPhone applications.  I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on the proper location I should be dropping these files.

I currently have created include and lib directories containing my headers and libraries under:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/MyCompany1.0.sdk/
```

But I was unsure if the iPhoneOS.platform directory was a no-no.  If I should just be placing these in my own completely isolated area, not sitting parallel to Apple SDKs like this.

My libraries target the iPhone, so it seemed like the appropriate place to have them organized.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put them where ever you want. Personally I keep them in a subfolder of my iphone projects directory under my home, but I am the only dev on my computer.